# Bootstrap 3 tooltip hide

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I've a tooltip on a button in a bootstrap dropdown and whenever i click that button, i am hiding the button and showing another button. But previous button's tooltip does not hide until i moved the scroll vertically or horizontally.

```
<a (click)="hideThis();"
   rel="tooltip" data-title="Düzenle"
   data-placement="left"></a>
```

I don't think it's a **trigger: focus** problem because like i said when i moved the scroll, it disappears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that focus stays on the button after button hide. Change trigger to hover for all the tooltip will solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({ trigger: "hover" });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but these jQuery solutions didn't solve my problem, i guess i tried all. I am using this tooltip on Angular 2 so i was hiding the button with *ngIf="somethingTrue" and changed it to [hidden]="somethingFalse" and it worked.